# Concatenating strings in SAP Query

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-query

I'm creating a BAPI for SAP R/3. The equivalent in MSSQL of what I'm trying to write is this:

```
select
    bkpf.BELNR,
    bkpf.BUKRS,
    bkpf.GJAHR,
    bkpf.AWKEY
into
    #tab
from
    bkpf
where
    exists ( select 1 from #n_tab n where CONCAT(n.BELNR, n.GJAHR) = bkpf.AWKEY )
;
```

But apparently Open Sql doesn't allow operations in queries. So for what I researched, the table I want to "join" must be retrieved to an in memory table, create a new column in a loop doing the operation and the compare with the #tab table. But I'm struggling with the syntax. What I have so far is something like this:

```
FUNCTION ZBAPI_TEST.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Local Interface:
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

select 
    bkpf~BELNR
    bkpf~BUKRS
    bkpf~GJAHR
    bkpf~AWKEY
into ITAB_BKPF
from bkpf.

loop at ITAB_BKPF.
ITAB_BKPF-chkey = CONCATENATE BELNR GJAHR.
modify ITAB_BKPF.
endloop.

ENDFUNCTION.
```

But I'm getting the following errors.

> Field "ITAB_BKPF" is unknown. It is neither in one of the
>   specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.
>
> Field "ITAB_BKPF-GJAHR" is unknown. It is neither in one of
>   the   specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.
>
> Incorrect nesting: Before the statement "ENDFUNCTION", the
>   control structure introduced by "SELECT" must be concluded with
>   "ENDSELECT".
>
> Incorrect nesting: Before the statement
>   "+END-OF-INCLUDE", the control    structure introduced by "FUNCTION" must
>   be concluded with "ENDFUNCTION".

There's clearly an open statement. But I'm not really familiar with the language and don't know where the period is required or if I misplaced any closing statement. Other approach I saw online was with a construct `SELECT..ENDSELECT`:

```
FUNCTION ZBAPI_TEST.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Local Interface:
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

select
    bkpf~belnr
    bkpf~bukrs
    bkpf~gjahr
    bkpf~awkey
into corresponding fields
    wa_bkpf
from bkpf.

wa_bkpf-chkey = concatenate belnr gjahr.
append wa_bkpf to itab_bkpf.
endselect.

ENDFUNCTION.
```

But this generate a new batch of errors:

> Field "CORRESPONDING" is unknown. It is neither in one of the
>   specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.        Field
>   "WA_BKPF-CHKEY" is unknown. It is neither in one of the
>   specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.        Field "WA_BKPF"
>   is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables nor defined
>   by a "DATA" statement.

I suspect the solutions and examples I found online skip some part where they define some of the structures they use. But I don't really know how to do it. Can someone help?

EDIT:
The final code looks like that:

```
types: begin of t_bkpf,
            belnr type belnr_d,
            bukrs type bukrs,
            gjahr type gjahr,
            awkey type awkey,
            chkey type string.
types: end of t_bkpf.
data: itab_bkpf type standard table of t_bkpf.
field-symbols: <wa> type t_bkpf.

    select
        BELNR
        BUKRS
        GJAHR
        AWKEY
    into corresponding fields of table ITAB_BKPF
    from bkpf.

    loop at ITAB_BKPF assigning <wa>.
      CONCATENATE <wa>-BELNR <wa>-GJAHR into <wa>-chkey.
    endloop.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

manoftheyear.

Let me know if this works for you:

```
*** Definition of custom type.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_bkpf,
        belnr TYPE bukrs,
        bukrs TYPE belnr_d,
        gjahr TYPE gjahr,
        awkey TYPE awkey,
        chkey TYPE string,    " Replace with the type you need to use.
       END OF ty_bkpf.

*** Definition of internal table of custom type.
DATA lt_bkpf TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_bkpf.

*** Definition of field symbol (pointer) of custom type.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <lfs_bkpf> TYPE ty_bkpf.


*** Extraction of data from BKPF database table.
SELECT belnr bukrs gjahr awkey
  FROM bkpf
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_bkpf.

*** Checks if extraction was succesful.
IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL.

  UNASSIGN <lfs_bkpf>.

*** Loop internal table...
  LOOP AT lt_bkpf ASSIGNING <lfs_bkpf>.

*** ...and create value for field CHKEY.
    CONCATENATE <lfs_bkpf>-belnr
                <lfs_bkpf>-gjahr
           INTO <lfs_bkpf>-chkey.  " By using a pointer, there's no need to use MODIFY sentence.

  ENDLOOP.

ENDIF.
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. I arrived at a similar solution (should I edit it in the original question?) and will accept this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT directly on QUERY. Example:

```
SELECT SINGLE CONCAT( CONCAT( a~name1, a~name2 ), a~name3 )
        FROM ( ( adrc AS a
             INNER JOIN j_1bbranch AS j ON a~addrnumber = j~adrnr )
             INNER JOIN t001w AS t ON j~cgc_branch = t~j_1bbranch
      AND j~bukrs = @i_postab-bukrs
      AND t~werks = @e_postab-prctr+4(4) )
      INTO @e_postab-company_name.
```